# removing/check if there are duplicates from array and saving/updating the array dynamically in localstorage (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this function to push data into the array and save it in localstorage. My problem is that my function pushes to the array/saves to localstorage even though the same profileID exists. I want something that checks if the same profileId already exists remove the object and from localstorage/array then push to local storage/array. In short i do not want duplicates of the same profileID saved in localstorage or the array. I also want to keep the most new object instead of old and new saved in the array for the same profilID

```
 
  PUSHData(){
    var myobj = {
      Button: this.isReadMore,
       Class: this.sampleElem.className,
      ProfiliD: this.id,

    };
   
    
    const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CollapseState'));
    if(saved != null){
      this.array.push(myobj);
      localStorage.setItem('CollapseState',JSON.stringify(this.array));
    }else{
      this.array.push(myobj);
      localStorage.setItem('CollapseState',JSON.stringify(this.array));

    }
```

this is what localStorage looks like now

```
0: {Button: true, Class: "ShowHide", ProfiliD: "115279"}
1: [{Button: true, Class: "ShowHide", ProfiliD: "115279"},…]
  0: {Button: true, Class: "ShowHide", ProfiliD: "115279"}
  1: [{Button: true, Class: "ShowHide", ProfiliD: "115192"}]
```

I would really appreciatie any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `CollapseState` is containing an array of objects in a localStorage. You can follow below steps to achieve this requirement **:**

- Check if CollapseState array exist in localStorage or not (which you already doing)

  ```
  const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CollapseState'));
  ```
- Now as `saved` will be an array, You can iterate over it to check if `ProfiliD` exist or not. If exist, splice/remove the object from the array.

  ```
  saved.forEach((o, index) => {
    if (o.ProfiliD === myobj.ProfiliD) {
      saved.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  ```
- Now push the `newObj` into the saved array.

  ```
  saved.push(newObj);
  ```
- Final step, set this updated `saved` array into the localStorage.

  ```
  localStorage.setItem('CollapseState',JSON.stringify(saved));
  ```

Comment: @KILLUA If possible please do accept this answer so that it will help other fellow developers as well if they face same issue in future.

Comment: Done :) new here, did not know that :)

Answer (score 0):

you should update existing item in array instead of push new one when same ProfiliD exists in localStorage:

```js
PUSHData(){
    var myobj = {
      Button: this.isReadMore,
       Class: this.sampleElem.className,
      ProfiliD: this.id,

    };
   
    
    const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CollapseState'));
    if(saved != null){
      this.array[this.array.findIndex(x=>x.ProfiliD == myobj.ProfiliD)] = myobj;
      localStorage.setItem('CollapseState',JSON.stringify(this.array));
    }else{
      this.array.push(myobj);
      localStorage.setItem('CollapseState',JSON.stringify(this.array));

    }
}
```

Comment: thx. this removes the whole array and update it with the new profileID when i navigate to another profile and try to push a new profileID/object. Does not work for me. Thank you so much though.
What i want is if profilID/objects already exists update the array with the for the duplicates of profilID and otherwise just push into the array.

Your solution overwrites the hole array which i do not want that to happen. Only the duplicates based on ProfilID

Thank you so much though